# JSOM oListItem is undefined

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, jsom

I am using JSOM to update an item in a list, which I've had no problem with in the past.  But for some odd reason I'm getting an error that I'm not sure about.  Maybe I'm overlooking something small.  see below

```
 var siteUrl = _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl
 var clientContext = new SP.ClientContext(siteUrl);
 var oList = clientContext.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('Document Approval');
 this.oListItem = oList.getItemById(promise.responseJSON.d.results[0].ID);

 oListItem.set_item('Role Status', roleStatus); //<-- Error Here
 oListItem.update();

 clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddSucceeded),
     Function.createDelegate(this, this.onAddFailed)
 );
```

Here's the error I get  **'oListItem' is undefined**

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have not defined oListItem.

Declare oListItem as a variable.

i.e. `var oListItem = oList.addItem(itemCreateInfo);`

Edit: For update list item

As compared from the [Microsoft Document](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v%3Doffice.14))

```
oListItem.set_item('Title', 'My Updated Title'); // both the parameters of set_item function accepts string where the first string parameter denotes the field name and the second string parameter denotes the value of the item to be set.
```

Comment: I actually meant that to be an update.  I updated my question but I will declare and see if that works.  It didn't show it in the microsoft example.  https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/developer/sharepoint-2010/hh185011(v%3Doffice.14)

Comment: I have edited the answer. Please check.

Comment: Thanks that worked, but it generated a different error.  I posted the new question here...  https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/250205/jsom-error-unable-to-get-property-apply